# Display the Products sku that customer ordered in excel sheet

Tags: magento-1.9

**Background** :

I can able to download excel sheet with customer's information....

**Requirement** :

Now i am trying to get Which products customer ordered ?

**Issue** :

In all the rows , its displaying same product skus....

[image]

```
<?php

$customerCount = 0;
try
{
    //configure the customer collection 
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')   
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

      //configure the order collection 
    $ordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order_item', 
    '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', 
        array(
              'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')
             )
    )->group('main_table.customer_id');

    do
    {       
         foreach ($collection as $customer)
         {
            foreach ($ordercollection as $data)
            {   
             $product = $data->getSkus();
            }                                  
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
            $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Last name'] = $customerArray['lastname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];                      
            $customerREquiredArray['product'] = $product;           
         }         
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this logic because in your logic there is not relation between order and customer id.

```
$j=0;
    foreach ($collection as $customer)
             {

               $newordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerArray['entity_id']);

    $orderIds = $newordercollection->getAllIds();
    $ordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in',$orderIds));
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order_item', 
    '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', 
        array(
              'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')
             )
    )->group('main_table.customer_id');
               $firtItem = $ordercollection->getFIrstItem();
                 $product = $firtItem->getSkus();

                $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
                $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
                $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
                $customerREquiredArray['Last name'] = $customerArray['lastname'];
                $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];                      
                $customerREquiredArray['product'] = $product; 
                $j=$j+1;          
             }
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error, i can't able to find out where? , `right syntax to use near ')))) GROUP BY `main_table`.`customer_id`' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ") AS `skus` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON `sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id WHERE (((main_table.entity_id = 'in') OR (()))) GROUP BY `main_table`.`customer_id`
` please check code : https://pastebin.com/fXRAdPnn

Comment: @BabyinMagento just put the check if customer have order's.

Comment: only some customers have orders, not all customers...... or may be we deleted some orders.....

Comment: just put check of `if( $orderIds): //then condition endif;`

Comment: still getting same syntax error , here is updated code : https://pastebin.com/yqKYgjv3